# Want to change colors of SVG loaded using <object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

So I am loading the SVG this way:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/pro.svg"></object>
```

and in the browser it appears this way:

[image]

So now I want to change that fill color of cls-1 and cls-2. 
I tried to change the color of the class .cls-2 and .cls-1 using style tag, and tried using Js and Jquery to add it after loading. both of these way did not work, it seemed like it did not recognized those classes.

So is it possible? I do not mind to try another way to load the SVG img, it is just that this is the only way that allowed me to change its size freely as will as see(and hopefully manipulate) each part's color of it, all while maintaining a small piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a special stylesheet declaration **inside** the SVG, just before the opening SVG tag. It's similar but not identical to HTML's `link` element. Something like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="320"
     height="240"
     viewBox="0 0 320 240">
    <rect id="r" class="foo" x="10" y="10" width="300" height="200"/>
</svg>
```

If there are rules for class `foo` in the css file, they will be applied to the `rect`.

This should work with `<object>` in the way you mention. No need to load the same css file into html.

To change the appearance at runtime, you should be able to access the SVG elements.

Pure js:

```
var r = document.querySelector("#r");
r.classList.remove("foo");
r.classList.add("bar");
```

Just remember that [CSS properties for SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/style.html) are not the same as for HTML.

Comment: Oh, I just discovered that IE11 (Win 8.1) has no support for classList in SVG. You might be able to use setAttribute or setAttributeNS, but if you have more than one class name, you'll have to mess about parsing them